# MySQL shortening select query

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi There StackOverflow peoples!

I need to reduce the subquery of my select statement, mainly because there is just so much to select:

```
SELECT
    `p`.id
,   (SELECT a.title FROM products_types_attributes a WHERE a.filtername = 'filter_01' AND a.ttv_end IS null AND a.id = p.filter_01) AS filter_01
,   (SELECT a.title FROM products_types_attributes a WHERE a.filtername = 'filter_02' AND a.ttv_end IS null AND a.id = p.filter_02) AS filter_02
,   (SELECT a.title FROM products_types_attributes a WHERE a.filtername = 'filter_03' AND a.ttv_end IS null AND a.id = p.filter_03) AS filter_03
,   (SELECT a.title FROM products_types_attributes a WHERE a.filtername = 'filter_04' AND a.ttv_end IS null AND a.id = p.filter_04) AS filter_04
FROM
    `products` p
LEFT JOIN
    `products_types` t
    ON p.type_id = t.id
    AND t.ttv_end IS null
WHERE
    `p`.`id` = 9754
AND    `p`.`ttv_end` IS null
```

There are 50+ filters, and while typing them in one by one is one way, i was wondering if there was a shorter way to code it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to join products_types_attributes table

Comment: could you elaborate? ive tried it different ways, but they duplicate the id with different filters, not one id with several filters as tabs

Comment: duplicate id then use different aliases.

Comment: Sorry im am still new with sql, could you give a sample query

Comment: No chance. You will have to type all the filters to get them. Your data model seems a bit strange, by the way. Why name the filters 1, 2, 3, etc. and have the number redundantly in filtername of products_types_attributes and in the column name p.filter_xx? Is it important which filter comes first and which next? Shouldn't it be rather an unordered set of filters? Why are the products_types_attributes not linked to products_types as the name suggests, but to products instead?

Comment: I have no idea. im using codes from an older version from someone else and i cant be bothers to fix it really. Thanks anyway

Comment: If this is essentially "pivoting", see this Stored Proc to do the work for you:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    `p`.id
,   f1.title AS filter_01
,   f2.title AS filter_02
,   f3.title AS filter_03
,   f4.title AS filter_04
FROM
    `products` p
LEFT JOIN
    `products_types` t
    ON p.type_id = t.id
    AND t.ttv_end IS null
LEFT JOIN products_types_attributes f1 on f1.filtername = 'filter_01' AND a.ttv_end IS null AND a.id = p.filter_01
LEFT JOIN products_types_attributes f2 on f1.filtername = 'filter_02' AND a.ttv_end IS null AND a.id = p.filter_02
LEFT JOIN products_types_attributes f3 on f1.filtername = 'filter_03' AND a.ttv_end IS null AND a.id = p.filter_03
LEFT JOIN products_types_attributes f4 on f1.filtername = 'filter_04' AND a.ttv_end IS null AND a.id = p.filter_04
WHERE
    `p`.`id` = 9754
AND    `p`.`ttv_end` IS null
```

Comment: Thank you, but i was thinking of reducing the number of filters i had to type manually, i.e filter_01 - filter_50 as an array and the sql statement looping or something so i dont have to type it in every time i want to change it

Comment: if you need all the fields filter 01-50 you ahve to type them. May be I don't understand the question

Comment: so i do have to type them in? no way around it?